# Memory leak in stacks/queues c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stack

I have an assignment to write a Stacks class using a list and a Queue class using two Stacks. I've completed the assignment, but running the valgrind I find that I have a memory leak in the following code:

```
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    T *n = new T;
    *n = myStack.front();
    myStack.pop_front();
    return *n;
}
```

I can't delete the pointer after I return it so I'm not sure how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you even need to use new? You can make a copy of the stack's top value like this:

```
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    T n = myStack.front();
    myStack.pop_front();
    return n;
}
```

So there are no allocations and no leaks;

Comment: I actually tried this, but it didn't work at the time. Probably was careless and mistyped something. Works now though, thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Note that this is only strongly exception-safe if move-constructing a `T` is a no-throw operation. If it can throw (or if `T` only has a throwing copy-constructor), then you could lose the data in the `T` if the copy in to the return value fails. If you want this operation to be no-throw (for reasonable `T`), then change the first line to `T n{std::move(myStack.front())};`

Answer (score 3):

Make a copy and then clear the memory if any inside pop_front.

```
    T Stack<T>::pop()
    {
        T ret = myStack.front();
        myStack.pop_front();        
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have rather used

```
T n = myStack.front();
```

Answer (score 0):

On your place, I would stop using raw pointers and change to shared_ptr. Is is much safer.

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple answers giving the correct code, but the reason your existing code was wrong goes something like this:

```
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    T *n = new T;          // allocates dynamic memory
    *n = myStack.front();  // reference to T from front() copied to allocated T object
    myStack.pop_front();   // removes the T in the stack
    return *n;  // copies your allocated T object to the return value
    // your pointer variable goes out of scope, that address is stored nowhere,
    // this is where the leak occurs...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

T *n = new T;
you are creating T using new and not using it. that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copying semantics is one of the biggest strengths of C++, because you can put the compiler and the author of type ´T´ to blame:

```
T Stack<T>::pop() // may throw
{
    T ret = myStack.front();
    myStack.pop_front();
    return ret;
}
```

Note though that this is a sub-ideal form of a pop-function. Upon copying, an exception might be thrown, which makes implementing an exception safe pop-function essentially impossible.

The container `std::stack<>` solves by making the return type `void`:

```
void Stack<T>::pop() // no-throw [if T is written by a sane coder]
{        
    myStack.pop_front();
}

T Stack<T>::back() // may throw
{        
    return myStack.front();
}
```

This provides you with a mean to clean up your stack upon destruction without throwing exceptions (throwing destructors in C++ is, by convention (not by the standard), forbidden).